# Email Server to only handle inbound messaging and routing

Tags: email, email-client

Was hoping for some ideas as to a service to which I can set up an inbound-only email system. In other words, I will have multiple users on the system, each can receive their own email... but at the moment... at this time, I am not focused on the ability to send or reply to messages, only receive them and send to the appropriate user. I looked into Postmark... They seem to have some great functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CloudMailin](https://www.cloudmailin.com) Is another alternative. However there are effectively three options for setting up something like this.

- Use an existing, traditional, email server and poll for the emails
- Setup your own email server and create a script to run when you receive an email
- Use a third party solution, as you've already mentioned.

I went through for of these for Rails a little while back [here](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/), but all the information is still relevant.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Smith, I am going through a third party solution for now (postmark), although... CloudMailin looks like a pretty good option as well. Through Postmark, I set up a subdomain mx record and pointed it to them, then I just have to parse whatever mail is sent to that subdomain.